# Person has no persona on the internet yet runs a business

Tags: identity

Original Question:

There is this older person (60+yrs) who is runs a business with internet presence yet when I do am internet search on him nothing pops up, not even photos!! How do I find out if he is a Government agent or somehow uses an alias?

Edit 10/21/14 for clarity:

In other words:

1. Is/are there any centralized government agent lists I can browse?
2. How do I search for a name change?
3. How do I request a background check on the internet?
4. How do I perform a business lookup on the internet
5. Where can I hire a private investigator?

Comment: You mean a person with no internet presence cannot run a business?

Comment: So even if he did have a Facebook profile, how would you find out if he's a government agent?

Comment: If I google my real name there are no photos. I think I might be a government agent :)

Comment: I'd comment on this question except it's going to get closed soon. Oh, wait...

Comment: I'm fairly sure that this Q&A site is a government front for the illuminati; but I post here anyway.

Comment: @Tokk, I just google'd myself to make sure ;)

Comment: @LateralFractal One of us! One of us!

Comment: You specific questions are country-specific. Which country? And none of those questions have anything to do with Info Security.

Comment: If someone were supposed to be a secret government agent, there's not really a very high chance that they'd list their name in a public database of government agents.

Answer (score 3):

If you are in the United States, each state government maintains a registry of businesses in that state.  Do a Google search like this: "register business georgia" (or whatever state the business is in.)  For many states, you can look at the business records on line; in some, you'll have to go to a government office.  That will tell you who owns the business and may provide other details.  I suspect, but do not know, that most other countries have similar registries.

Many people, including a member of my family, have no Internet presence.  It just doesn't seem important to him; nothing sinister about it.

If you are concerned that someone may be a "government agent" because you're thinking about buying or selling something illegal, *don't do it.*  Even if the business owner is an honest crook, it's a pretty safe bet that law enforcement knows about any illegal businesses operating on the Internet.  Try a search for "silk road."

If you are concerned that you will be cheated in an otherwise legal transaction, do a search for the business name.  Businesses that cheat people turn up in reviews all over the place.

Answer (score 0):

Any normal business needs to register with the Chamber of Commerce or whatever it is called in the country from which he runs his business. So check there.

Even then - he can be a government agent!